# ruragrch package using dummy variables in gjr garch

Tags: r, volatile, dummy-variable, arch

I am using the rugarch package estimate model(modifed GJR GARCH)

want to estimate the following model:

[image]

I would like to see spillover effect from US to others and change pre and post crisis but I don’t know how to do add pre and post dummy n rugarch.

Some code  just  put  dummy  in external.regressors parameter .

But, that case, they get only one coef like `vxreg1`

I want to compare variables before and after the global crisis.

Like this [image]

will be very grateful if you help me to get the solution